# Dart oauth2: sample not work

Tags: dart

I tried the sample code for dart oauth2 library from:
https://github.com/dart-gde/dart-google-oauth2-library

I followed the README,
create a new project from Google API console and set

```
Redirect URIs:  http://127.0.0.1:3030/oauth2callback
JavaScript origins: http://127.0.0.1:3030
```

then I change the client id in oauth_example.dart file, and run.
I can see a web page with a login button. I clicked it but nothing happens. 
Is anybody has experience about it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://blog.dartwatch.com/2013/04/sign-in-with-google-using-google-oauth2.html) tutorial. Very clear, step by step.

Comment: tutorial's link is broken.