# How do you use OAuth2 in dart 1.0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, dart, dart-polymer, dartium

I would like to use what looks like the [official library for OAuth2 in Dart](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/oauth2).  However there doesn't seem to be any complete examples nor documentation beyond the actual comments (and incomplete example) in the oauth2.dart source file.  Any kind of normal markdown docs seen with github back modules seem to be missing.  Also nothing is showing up in the [API reference](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/).

Wanted to add oauth2 to a polymer app but appears from what I can see that the library only supports server side.  Is this accurate?

Am I looking in the wrong place for the information?

Comment: Related (with a link to a good tutorial): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076541/dart-oauth2-sample-not-work

Answer (score 2):

I found this open issue [Sample for OAuth2 login](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=14260)

Answer (score 1):

For more information on using he Google APIs and the different options for OAuth2 take a look at the following packages:

- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis_auth
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis_beta

See http://news.dartlang.org/2014/09/new-google-apis-client-libraries-for.html for the announcement of these packages.

There is also additional documentation here: https://www.dartlang.org/googleapis/.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Can you please add at least a simple code example to your answer to make it a good answer?

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a more complete solution beyond google oauth.  Like a library handling facebook/linkedin/etc.  Similar to the APIs available in Node & ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [tilebasedwordsearch](https://github.com/johnmccutchan/tilebasedwordsearch/tree/master).

It's a pretty complete example using the Google OAuth2 library on the client side.